# Find a subset of length 4 which has a maximum value of sum

Tags: python

So I need a solution for this example without using queue.
For example [1, 5, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 15, 1, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3] max sum of 4 elements here is 35 [11, 3, 6, 15].
This is my 'logical' code but I don't know why is not working.

```
array = [1, 5, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 15, 1, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3]

k = 4
current_sum = 0
max_sum = -1
n = len(array)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        if j < k:
            current_sum += array[j]
            continue
        
        
        if current_sum > max_sum: 
            max_sum = current_sum            


print(f"Max sum is {max_sum}")
```

Comment: `max([sum(array[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(array))])`   would something like this work?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"not working" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Chris's solution is a list comprehension.  Look it up.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Comprehensions are a *really* neat feature of Python, and you should read the entire range of examples.  Individual spot tutorials are out of scope here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers have given correct solutions to your problem, but I'm going to go over why your code isn't working.

```
if j < k:
```

If your code was working properly you'd expect `j` to be `0, 1, 2, 3` on the first time through the outer loop, then `1, 2, 3, 4` on the second time, etc. This means you shouldn't be comparing `j` to `k`, you should be comparing `j` to `i+k`.

```
continue
```

In general, continue shouldn't be used when possible. It makes the flow of the code hard to follow. Instead of using `continue` I'm going to change a different part of your code:

```
for j in range(i, n):
```

It makes sense that you're starting at `i`, but why are you going to n? If you only want j to be 4 numbers, you should stop it at those 4 numbers. Let's change this to `for j in range(i, i+k):`

Now we just need to make a couple more changes. You don't want to check `current_sum` before you're done adding it up, so let's put `if current_sum > max_sum` inside the outer `for` loop. And don't forget to reset `current_sum` to 0 after each iteration through the outer loop!

Lastly, we need to make sure we don't go out of range of the array. We'll do this by changing `for i in range(n):` to `for i in range(n-k):`.

The final code:

```
array = [1, 5, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 15, 1, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3]

k = 4
current_sum = 0
max_sum = -1
n = len(array)

for i in range(n-k):
    for j in range(i, i+k):
        current_sum += array[j]
        
    if current_sum > max_sum: 
        max_sum = current_sum
    current_sum = 0

print(f"Max sum is {max_sum}")
```

There are still some problems with this code, like when `array` has a length less than 4, but this fixes all the initial problems you had.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (using a loop, similar to what you had before)

```
array = [1, 5, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 15, 1, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3]

k = 4
current_sum = 0
max_sum = -1
n = len(array)

for i in range(n):
    current_sum = sum(array[i:i+k])
    if current_sum > max_sum:
        max_sum = current_sum


print(f"Max sum is {max_sum}")
```

Option 2: Using list comprehension (thanks Chris for the idea)

```
array = [1, 5, 7, 2, 11, 3, 6, 15, 1, 5, 0, 7, 6, 3]

k = 4

max_sum = max([sum(array[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(array))])
```